# NodeJS params.Example not being used by @sendgrid/mail

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, watson-assistant, sendgrid-api-v3

Watson Assistant passes my params.finalemail and params.guestemail correctly. It looks like your @sendgrid/mail is not accepting the values of these params. Why is that?

Basically, Watson passes the $guest email as the "to" email address and the $finalemail contain the main body of the email.

I need my function to send an email with the information contained in the above varibles.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
 /*    Replace YOUR-SENDGRID-API-KEY-GOES-HERE with
        the API Key you get from SendGrid.
  */
  sgMail.setApiKey('apikey')

function sendmail(params) {
params.guestemail
params.finalemail


  let msg = {}
  msg.to = params.guestemail
  msg.from = 'example@outlook.com'
  msg.subject = 'Your Reservation'
  msg.html = params.finalemail

  sgMail.send(msg,(error, json) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
  return { sent: 1 }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is happening and what you expect to happen so people can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just added more information.

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid will send either text field or html not both. To send the message that you want you can add 'This message is HTML only.' in an html tag.

Comment: I removed the plain text line completly. The params.guestemail and final mail is still not recognized.

Comment: Hi. I ran your program and it is working fine for me i.e. email being sent to params.guestemail with the body of params.finalemail.

Comment: That's weird. So does it mean my Watson Assistant is not passing the parameters correctly?